# jquery multiple conditions

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 checkboxes, each in a separate `<div>`. Each div has a corresponding class (widthCol1 -> widthCol4).
Each div is inside a separate `<td>` in a single `<tr>` of a `<table>`.
Depending on what combination of checkboxes are selected, I need to color the row of the table in a specific color.

Considering only the first 2 checkboxes it should color the row #ffaaaa when `.widthCol2 input` is checked and #ccff99 when it is not. Also it should color the row #fff if there is no checkbox selected (not implemented).

The script doesn't work if there is a second checkbox selected in other row. Why ?

```
$(".widthCol1 input").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if ($(".widthCol2 input").is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#ffaaaa");
        } else {
            $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#ccff99");
        }
    } else {
        // test other checkboxes before coloring #fff
    }
});
```

This script will have to be used for all 4. Is there also a better, cleaner way to test them ?

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle for your problem and give a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution.
The script below (partial copy of mine) will retrieve every row in the table and then, will find the 3 checkboxes that I need. After that it will test them and assign to color the correct color code. In the end it will assign the color to the row. In this way I only need to concern myself with 3 variables and not all the checkboxes (with their specific index) that are in the table.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    var vals = $(this).closest("tr");
    vals.each(function () {
        var color = "#fff";
        var c1 = $(this).find(".widthCol1 input:checkbox");
        var c2 = $(this).find(".widthCol2 input:checkbox");
        var c3 = $(this).find(".widthCol3 input:checkbox");
        if ($(c2).is(":checked")) {
            color = "#ffaaaa";
        } else {
            $(c1).is(":checked") ? color = "#ccff99" : color = "#fff";
        }
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt3RX/

I would suggest you try to formalize your logic, so you can lookup the correct color by checks.
Maybe it's as simple as 0=white, 1=green, 2=red, 3=purple (or what not), where the counter just counts all checked boxes.

Comment: I have updated the http://jsfiddle.net/Xt3RX/6/ to better reflect the html that is in my case.
The script does not work correctly in this regard.
Whenever there is a checkbox selected from the second column, all the other checkboxes from the first column will take it into consideration irrelevant of the row. But it should only care about the checkboxes from it's own row.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt3RX/8/ the code var vals = $("input[type='checkbox']"); is grabbing the values from all the checkboxes right ? How can I grab the values one row at a time ?